# Server Pc Clock Is Delayed

Tags: clock, windows-server-2012, system-clock

I have a Windows 2012 Server and client PS's get clock data from the server but server clock delays like 5 mins in 6 months. How can I fix that?

Comment: post the code that fetch time

Comment: Is the server not connected to the Internet? Does he not have an upstream NTP server configured?

Comment: Its not about that, just the watch that shows time information. Client pc's take this from server, so our office clock is always late. I read number 123 udp port syncronizes that so i opened that port but still same

Comment: It has internet connection but I dont know what is NTP server configure @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Do some research. Google for "Windows server time server"

Comment: I did but didnt work:( i tried port123, i check location settings etc.. @JonathonReinhart